# Dynamic Select EntityFramework and System.Linq.Dynamic

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

Im using the DynamicQueryable.Select() // dynamic select library

The only docu I have found so far is [System.Linq.Dynamic docu](http://www.lcs.syr.edu/faculty/fawcett/handouts/CoreTechnologies/CSharp/samples/CSharpSamples/LinqSamples/DynamicQuery/Dynamic%20Expressions.html#_Dynamic_Expression_API)

I have this query with anonymous return type which works.

```
var result = Context.Set<TPocoText>().Where((Expression<Func<TPocoText, bool>>) whereLambda)
                     .OrderByDescending(t => t.RowVersion).Skip(skip).Take(take)
                     .Select("new (m1,m2,Nav1) ");
```

and this works like `select(t=> new {t.m1,t.m2,t.Nav1})`  as expected

my Question
**How can it do the equivalent of select(t=> new {t,t.Nav1})**

i tried  .Select("new (it,Nav1) ")
and  .Select("new (this,Nav1) ")

the result was a parse error member not found.
Anybody know this dynamic string parsing API?

OR the equivalent **Expression** building syntax is also an option.

NOTE:The Nav Property ForSourceRecord is only known at runtime otherwise i would just use the normal lambda expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done using anon types. The compiler just doesn't have the information needed to work, especially with the free text/string approach.

Try this...

```
var param = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(TPocoText));
var init = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.MemberInit(
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(typeof(Foo)),
    new []{
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Bind(GetMemberInfo((Foo f) => f.Nav), System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "NameOfPropertyToBindToNav")),
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Bind(GetMemberInfo((Foo f) => f.M1), System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "M1")),
    }
);
var result = Context.Set<TPocoText>().Where((Expression<Func<TPocoText, bool>>) whereLambda)
                 .OrderByDescending(t => t.RowVersion).Skip(skip).Take(take)
                 .Select(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<TPocoText, Foo>>(init, param));



public class Foo
{
    public string Nav {get;set;}
    public string M1 {get;set;}
}
public static MemberInfo GetMemberInfo<T, U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> expression)
{
    var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (member != null)
        return member.Member;

    throw new ArgumentException("Expression is not a member access", "expression");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Aron.   the trick was the extra MemberInfo .  Im new to expression trees.   Very helpful, although it didnt compile, it was enough to show what to do :-)

Comment: Note f.Nav is not available at compile time

Comment: I didnt get this approach working. since f.nav only works in a dynamic way. You answered the question "cant be done using anon". And showed basically how an Expression tree could be built to solve the problem. A small piece of the solution must remain dynamic.  build one part of the body dynamically is the solution.  For now i will use every member individually as this works more simply.