# Dynamically passing properties in Select for projection in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there a way to pass the properties I want to retrieve from the DB in a Select dynamically, I don't know the properties I need beforehand and I don't want to write the conditions in my repository.

I don't want to retrieve all the fields at once, just the ones I need based on some conditions.

For example:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Property1 {get; set;}
    public string Property2 {get; set;}
    //other properties here

    [NotMapped]
    public string Selected 
    { 
        if(condition)
            return Property1;
        else
            return Property2;
    }
}
```

and in the service layer I have

```
query.Select(s => new StudentViewModel
{
    Value = s.Selected; //this one will get the property we want based on a condition

    //other stuff here
    //OtherValue = s.OtherProperty
}
).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) and Projections to achieve that.

Comment: @Rabban That won't help, OP is talking about selecting specific columns from the database here.

Comment: @DavidG AutoMapper does that with .ProjectTo<Type>(), it selects only the fields that the projected type uses.

Comment: Yes, but OP doesn't know what the properties are going to be so doesn't have a type to project to.

Comment: DavidG you are right, I want to project specific columns for the database, and those columns are not known beforehand.

Comment: @akr and how you are going to use query result?

Comment: You can probably do this with Dynamic Linq or something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333325/dynamic-select-entityframework-and-system-linq-dynamic)

Comment: @akr and @DavidG its still possible with AutoMapper. You can select this within the mapping of `StudentViewModel` or if the condition is outside the DB you can derive multiple classes from `StudentViewModel` each for a different condition and project them.

Comment: @Rabban No it's not, you are missing the point. OP doesn't know which columns are required until run-time.

Comment: @DavidG maybe i'm missing the point or maybe you have not enough experience with AutoMapper. But you can achieve that with it, even when you only know the condition at runtime. We don't know enough in what kind the conditions comes, but currently i see no barrier with AutoMapper.

Comment: @Rabban  this will leave me with many many derived classes each for specific case, the real case is much more complicated than the example

Comment: @akr You are right, the derived class will produce too much overhead. As what will the condition come?

Comment: @Rabban there are multiple conditions in my case, they can be checking other values in the class, computed values or other external parameters passed.

Comment: @DavidG using Dynamic Linq will make my Select look ugly with all the strings that are my property names, I was hoping there will be an simpler solution

Comment: @akr its difficult to suggest a solution without knowing how the conditions will look and how they will be computed. Maybe you can edit your question to clarify and explain a little bit more about your conditions.

Comment: @Rabban one of the simplest conditions is checking an external boolean property from another utility class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Selector**

An easy but ugly way is to use a Selector:

```
query.Select(Selector()).FirstOrDefault();
```

And the Selector can look like this:

```
private static Expression<Func<Student, StudentViewModel>> Selector()
{
    if (Condition())
        return x => new StudentViewModel
        {
            Name = x.Property1,
            OtherName = x.OtherName
        };

    return x => new StudentViewModel
    {
        Name = x.Property2,
        OtherName = x.OtherName
    };
}
```

As you can see the obviously downside here is that you need to copy/paste all other selected properties. That is why its ugly.

**AutoMapper**

1. **Configs**

   You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) with different configurations. First you need to define a standard mapping for all properties that don't need to be dynamic.

   ```
   public static void AddStandardStudentMap(this IMappingExpression<Student, StudentViewModel> map)
   {
       map.ForMember(dest => dest.OtherName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OtherProperty))
          .ForMember(dest => dest.OtherName2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OtherProperty2));
       // you can concat .ForMember() for each property you need.
   }
   ```

   Next, you need to define the different configs and add the `AddStandardStudentMap` method to each invidual mapping.

   ```
   var config1 = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
       cfg.CreateMap<Student, StudentViewModel>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Property1))
       .AddStandardStudentMap()
   );

   var config2 = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
       cfg.CreateMap<Student, StudentViewModel>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Property2))
           .AddStandardStudentMap()
       );
   ```

   After this, just use your conditions to decide which config do you need

   ```
   IConfigurationProvider provider;
   if(Condition())
       provider = config1;
   else
       provider = config2;
   ```

   And then instead of `.Select()` use:

   ```
   query.ProjectTo<StudentViewModel>(provider).FirstOrDefault();
   ```

   As we can see this solution is still ugly and has a lot of overhead but its needed in some cases, thats why i stated it here.
2. **Expression**

   This is a bit similar to the Configs but brings you more flexibility and less writing effort.

   First create a config but this time with a Selector

   ```
   var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
   cfg.CreateMap<Student, StudentViewModel>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.OtherName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OtherName))
       .ForMember(dest => dest.OtherName2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OtherName2))
       // and so on. Map all your properties that are not dynamically.

       // and then the Selector
       .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Selector()))
   );
   ```

   The Selector method can look like this:

   ```
   private static Expression<Func<Student, StudentViewModel>> Selector()
   {
       if(Condition())
           return src => src.Property1;
       else
           return src => src.Property2;
   }
   ```

   And then just use it like the configs solution but without selecting a particular config:

   ```
   query.ProjectTo<StudentViewModel>(config).FirstOrDefault();
   ```

**Conclusion**

I know this is a lot input and there are even more possibilities to achieve the behaviour that you want, with or without AutoMapper. But i would suggest you (grounded on the information you gave us) to use AutoMapper with Expressions. It should give the flexibility you need and is extensible for further requirements.

Comment: I would like to explore more solutions without the use of AutoMapper, because I'm in the middle of a project and I'm not really comfortable in introducing AutoMapper now, I was looking at your first solution, can I do something similar but like this: `query.Select(s => new StudentViewModel
{
    Value = Selector();

    //other stuff here
    //OtherValue = s.OtherProperty
}
).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @akr I'm afraid thats not easily possible. You need to rebuild functionality which is still present in AutoMapper. I know, i know, by now i sound like a AutoMapper salesman^^ but i can assure you that i'm not related to it. I just appreciate the functionality of it. If you have the possibility to add it to your Project, just do it. Its only one dependency, its in Nuget, its well document, it has a huge user base and its written for cases like this. If you have the choice, don't reinvent the wheel.